# How to create unique links which expires after a day?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, web-deployment

I have some data coming from webhook, whenever a user make changes to another client website. The webhook sends data to me. I want to create a page where the data from webhook is shown. For this, I want to create a unique link that expires after a day , I am able to generate the unqiue link  name using hashing algorithm, but how to deploy this? I am new to deployment stuff. Technology used is AWS, node js for backend , and mongodb for Database, Angular for frontend.

Comment: The unique link should include an expiry timestamp, and that timestamp should be included in the hash to ensure it cannot be changed. When processing the link, your app should check that the timestamp has not expired yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Lambda and API Gateway to deploy your NodeJS code. Your compiled Angular code can be hosted in S3 + CloudFront (Static / Frontend only content). And if you want fully-managed MongoDB on AWS then MongoDB Atlas is the solution (https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb-atlas/).

As far as how to deploy all this infra; you have few options. You can use Terraform, AWS CDK or Serverless Framework (not recommended in this case). If you're already familiar with Node (JS or TS) then AWS CDK is a good choice for you.

You can AWS Codepipeline to deploy your application.